# Mysql query insert new row

Tags: php, mysql

i have this three tables
Retailer, imovo, rbpos_epos. 
What i do is i match them, and get a result which i print in in a page.

What i need to do is insert those results into a new table, i will make a "Match" button which will query the two tables retailer and imovo, and the matches will go to the new table named :matching.

What i need in order to avoid duplications.. is to remove from the retailer table and imovo the matched rows..

Here is the query i use to match:

```
 $data = mysql_query( "select r.`time`, r.`epos_id`, r.`date`,re.`location`,i.`user_id`,i.`mobile_number`,
       i.`time`, i.`rbpos_id`, i.`date`
from retailer r
join rbpos_epos re on r.epos_id = re.epos_id
join imovo i on i.rbpos_id = re.rbpos_id
             and addtime(r.`time`, '0:0:50') > i.`time`
             and r.`time` < i.`time`
             and r.`date` = i.`date`;
") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 Print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
  Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th>Date:</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Location</th>
<th>User ID</th> 
<th>Mobile Number</th>"; 
  Print "</tr>";
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 

   Print "<tr>"; 
 Print " <td>".$info['date'] . "</td>
<td>".$info['time'] . " </td>
<td>".$info['location'] . " </td>
<td>".$info['user_id'] . " </td>
<td>".$info['mobile_number'] . " </td>
</tr>"; 
 }
```

The printed rows are those i need to insert in the matching table..
Thanks!

I tried this:

```
      $data = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO Matching(date, time, location, user_id, phone)
SELECT 
   r.`date`,
   `time`,
   re.`location`,
   i.`user_id`,
   i.`mobile_number`
from retailer r
join rbpos_epos re on r.epos_id = re.epos_id
join imovo i on i.rbpos_id = re.rbpos_id
and addtime(r.`time`, '0:0:50') > i.`time`
and r.`time` < i.`time`
and
```

r.`date` = i.`date`;
") 
But i get the error:

```
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html):

```
INSERT INTO Matching(date, time, location, user_id, phone)
SELECT 
   r.`date`,
   `time`,
   re.`location`,
   i.`user_id`,
   i.`mobile_number`
from retailer r
join rbpos_epos re on r.epos_id = re.epos_id
join imovo i on i.rbpos_id = re.rbpos_id
and addtime(r.`time`, '0:0:50') > i.`time`
and r.`time` < i.`time`
and r.`date` = i.`date`;
```

Then you have to do this `INSERT` when the button `match` is clicked.

**Update:** If you want to delete the matched rows. You can [`DELETE` with `JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html). Something like:

```
DELETE r, re, i
from retailer r
join rbpos_epos re on r.epos_id = re.epos_id
join imovo i on i.rbpos_id = re.rbpos_id
and DATE(r.`date`) = DATE(i.`date`);
```

This will delete all the matched rows from all of the three tables, as explained in the manual:

> For the multiple-table syntax, DELETE deletes from each tbl_name the
>   rows that satisfy the conditions.

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fafe6/1)

**Note that:** it is better to use single column `DATETIME` instead of two separate parts `date` and `time` like what I did in the demo. Then you can use the MySQL Date and time functions to control them, like what I did in the join condition `DATE(r.date) = DATE(i.date)`.

Comment: Thanks, could you please see my updated question? i tried this, but i must be doing smth wrong here..

Comment: @al_alb - You are selecting 8 columns using the `SELECT` clause, whereas, you are inserting into 5 columns only in the `INSERT` clause columns' list. You have to select only 5 columns to be inserted into the table with the `INSERT` clause. The counts has to be matched. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks very much :)
it works if i select r.time instead of 'time' it says it's ambiguous then...

One question please, how can i delete the matched rows from the two other tables.. because when i'll do the matching, maybe i'll duplicate the entries..

Comment: @al_alb - You can delete with the same join syntax you used with the `SELECT` as explained in the [MYSQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html), and I think it will delete from the two matched tables, it will delete any rows that satisfy the join condition. For the first issue of `r.time` instead of `time` please update your question with the same query you are using. It might be a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for the answers Mahmoud :)
I've updated it, but please could you help me with the query of the delete... I mean i understand it in principal but i don't know how to do it..

Comment: @al_alb - OK, I will updated my answer. Just wait a couple of minutes. I am at work now :(.

Comment: Mahmoud thanks very much :)
Of course i'll wait, is much too kind from your part :)

Comment: @al_alb - Sorry for late, See my edit. If there is any thing goes wrong, don't hesitate to ask. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, very very much !
If i could give it 100 votes i would :D
Thanks again!

Comment: @al_alb - You're welcome any time. There is no need to do this. It just was helpful that what I was looking for.